# Connecting VB to MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb6

I would like to ask some help on how to connect VB6 to MYSQL? Please provide references as well.

Many Thanks

Comment: You could use ODBC or OleDB. For that you need the appropriate driver or ole db provider for MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Google indicates you can use [ADO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms807027.aspx) and the [MySQL ODBC](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) drivers.

```
Dim strConnection$, conn As Connection 

'Fill in the placeholders with your server details'
strConnection = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=myServerAddress;" & _ 
   "Database=myDataBase;User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3"

Set conn = New Connection  
conn.Open strConnection
```

ODBC connection string for MySQL from [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#p30).

Warning: [air code](http://codebetter.com/blogs/brendan.tompkins/archive/2005/02/27/56126.aspx). I have never done this myself.

Comment: I've used code similar to this, and I can testify that it works.

Answer (score 0):

link : http://paulbradley.tv/37/

This code snippet demonstrates how to connect to a MySQL database from a Windows based application written in Visual Basic 6. By using the MySQL ODBC driver and the Microsoft Remote Data Object it is quite easy to connect and retrieve records from a MySQL database server.

■ Download and install the MySQL ODBC driver.

■ Set-up a MySQL username and password combination that will allow connections from any host. See MySQLs grant command.

■ Start a new Visual Basic project and add the Microsoft Remote Data Object - Using the menus select Project | References and then select the Microsoft Remote Data Object from the list.

Sample Code

```
Private Sub cmdConnectMySQL_Click()

Dim cnMySql As New rdoConnection
Dim rdoQry  As New rdoQuery
Dim rdoRS   As rdoResultset

' set up a remote data connection
' using the MySQL ODBC driver.
' change the connect string with your username,
' password, server name and the database you
' wish to connect to.

cnMySql.CursorDriver = rdUseOdbc
cnMySql.Connect = "uid=YourUserName;pwd=YourPassword;
    server=YourServerName;" & _
    "driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};
    database=YourDataBase;dsn=;"
cnMySql.EstablishConnection

' set up a remote data object query
' specifying the SQL statement to run.

With rdoQry
    .Name = "selectUsers"
    .SQL = "select * from user"
    .RowsetSize = 1
    Set .ActiveConnection = cnMySql
    Set rdoRS = .OpenResultset(
            rdOpenKeyset, rdConcurRowVer)
End With

' loop through the record set
' processing the records and fields.

Do Until rdoRS.EOF
    With rdoRS

    ' your code to process the fields
    ' to access a field called username you would
    ' reference it like !username

        rdoRS.MoveNext
    End With
Loop

' close record set
' close connection to the database

rdoRS.Close
cnMySql.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Remote Data Objects have been declared obsolete by Microsoft. I'd suggest trying ADO instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx#mdac_technologies_road_map_old_topic9

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <cpr/cpr.h>
#include <elmo.hpp>

void appInit(char *args) {

}

int main(int argc, char *argv) {

if (argc > 1) {
    appInit(argv);
} else {
    std::cout << "Usage: a.out [search keyword]" << std::endl;
}

int limit = 3;

cpr::Parameters parameters{{"query", input},
                    {"limit", "3"},
                    {"indent", "true"},
                    {"key", "AIzaSyA5Xr82w7LrJgaLPb99P4kVZzFlxYuPhng"}};

auto response = cpr::Get(cpr::Url{
    "https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search"}, parameters);

auto elmo = nlohmann::elmo::parse(response.text);
elmo.flatten();

for (int i=0; i<limit; i++) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    std::cout << elmo["/itemListElement/0/result/name"_elmo_pointer];
    //std::cout << elmo["/itemListElement/i/result/@type/0"_elmo_pointer] << std::endl;
    //std::cout << elmo["/itemListElement/i/result/@type/1"_elmo_pointer] << std::endl;
    std::cout << elmo["/itemListElement/0/result/description"_elmo_pointer] << std::endl;
    std::cout << elmo["/itemListElement/0/result/detailedDescription/articleBody"_elmo_pointer] << std::endl;
    std::cout << elmo["/itemListElement/0/result/image/url"_elmo_pointer] << std::endl;
}

//std::cout << json.dump(4) << std::endl;
}
```