# Connecting to MySQL from a VB6 application

Tags: mysql, vb6, mysql-error-1045

I am trying to connect to a local MySQL database from a VB6 application. Having read the answer given in this question, [Connecting VB to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084376/connecting-vb-to-mysql) I have set up my connection thus...

```
Private database_connection As ADODB.Connection
Set database_connection = New ADODB.Connection
database_connection.ConnectionString = _
"Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=mydb; " _
              " Username=myuser; Password=mypass; Option=3"
database_connection.Open
```

This gives me an error...

```
(1) Error#: -2147467259
    Desc. : [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver]Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
    Native Error: 1045
    SQL State: S1000
    Help Context: 0
    Help File:
```

Is this the right approach? And if so, it appears I need to create an account in the database for ODBC. Is that the case, or is there something else wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `User=myuser;` instead of `Username=myuser;`

Comment: thank you for that. It hasn't fixed the problem, but it has turned it into a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your username/password and if that username has accesrights to connect to database.

Comment: thank you. I can connect from the command line using the username and password, and perform assorted queries. (Cut'n'pasted to check for typos.)